# Flutter Sembast AddAll

Tags: database, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to insert a List of Users to the Sembast Database in Flutter. But this does not work - I always get the following Error:

```
Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>')
```

Just adding one User - works for me. I just have a problem in adding a List of Users.

```
Future insertAll(List<Users> users) async {
        print(jsonEncode(users));
        await _usersStore.addAll(
            await _db, jsonDecode(jsonEncode(users)));
      }
```

The print gives me following: [{"id":"f20ce2fb-d0db-11e9-9e8b-06ba1e206a58", "name":"Max", "lastName":"Mustermann"}]

Comment: What is your intention with `jsonDecode(jsonEncode(users))`? I guess you need to convert to List<Users> to List<Map<String, dynamic>>. Is there a function on `User` to produce Map<String, dynamic> mostly something like `toJson`? If yes, you can use `users.map((u) => u.toJson()).toList()` in place of `jsonDecode(jsonEncode(users))`.

Comment: Thank you - that works!

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is just that jsonDecode is not of the expected type. You should consider casting using a function such as:

```dart
/// This properly cast a decoded json list of object
List<Map<String, dynamic>> asMapList(dynamic list) {
  return (list as List)?.cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
}
```

A simple test like this should work (assuming db is an opened database):

```dart
test('jsonDecode', () async {
  var store = intMapStoreFactory.store();

  var list = [
    {'test': 'value'}
  ];

  var toAdd = jsonDecode(jsonEncode(list));

  try {
    // This fails
    await store.addAll(db, toAdd);
    fail('should fail');
  } catch (e) {
    expect(e, isNot(const TypeMatcher<TestFailure>()));
    print(e);
  }

  // This works!
  await store.addAll(db, asMapList(toAdd));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you use a foreach and insert one at a time?

I know it may not be what you are looking for but it is a way to keep working until you find a way to do it!

```
Future insertAll(List<Users> users) async {
    print(jsonEncode(users));
    users.foreach((user) async{
      // insert here
    });

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - You could retype your `User` class, because your error is because `Users` is typed as a `List<dynamic>` and you are passing and map.

2 - You could add a field in the `User` class : `List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>`

or simply use the `.add()` method.

I strongly recommend to use `.add()`